# Double Sided Sorting in Angular Js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a shown Table with fields filled. I want to do double sided arranging of columns. But, only single sided is working.

I tried slicing it to add swappable - and + adding to change order.

html file.

```
// For Product Table.
<table border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th ng-click="customOrderBy('id')">Id</th>
            <th ng-click="customOrderBy('name')">Name</th>
            <th ng-click="customOrderBy('age')">Age</th>
            <th ng-click="customOrderBy('school')">School</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr .....>
            <td>.....</td>
            <td>.....</td>
            <td>.....</td>
            <td>.....</td>
            <td>
                <!--Old Action Buttons  
                        <button .....>....</button>-->
                <button .....>.....</button>

                <!--Old Action Buttons  
                        <button .....>.....</button>-->
                <button .....>.....</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

app.js file function.

```
// Double Sided Sorting.
$scope.customOrderBy = function (columnName) {
    // var currentColumnName = $scope.myOrderBy.slice(1);
    // var currentDirection = $scope.myOrderBy.slice(0, 1);
    // var direction = '-';
    // if (columnName === currentColumnName) {
    //     direction = (currentDirection == '+' ? '-' : '+');
    // }
    // $scope.myOrderBy = direction + columnName;

    $scope.myOrderBy = columnName;
}
```

When I click on header order direction should change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your app.js's funtion customOrderBy with this.

It'll work.

**app.js file function.**

```
// Double Sided Sorting.
$scope.customOrderBy = function (columnName) {
    // var currentColumnName = $scope.myOrderBy.slice(1);
    // var currentDirection = $scope.myOrderBy.slice(0, 1);
    // var direction = '-';
    // if (columnName === currentColumnName) {
    //     direction = (currentDirection == '+' ? '-' : '+');
    // }
    // $scope.myOrderBy = direction + columnName;
    if ($scope.myOrderBy === columnName) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = '-' + columnName;
    }
    else if ($scope.myOrderBy === '-' + columnName) {
        $scope.myOrderBy = columnName;
    }
    else {
        $scope.myOrderBy = columnName;
    }
    // $scope.myOrderBy = columnName;
}
```

Comment: @Raghu B Did this worked for you...If yes, KIndly accept this answer...